# Vertical Text in PHPExcel Cell

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

How can I print text vertically in a cell using **PHPExcel** class ?

[image]

need to print like the above figure.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you can do by rotating text:

Try this code:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B7')->getAlignment()->setTextRotation(90);
```

Reference:

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/21676

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setRightToLeft(true);
```

**Refer:**  http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/75118

Answer (score 0):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:A'.$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow())
    ->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

more detalis [link](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/209754)